# Twig field collection theme get field id

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I am trying to get the field ID of of a field collection item being rendered in a field collection theme twig file: `field-collection-item--field-name.html.twig.`

I am able to render content using  `{{content.field_name}}` but I need a unique identifier to create an anchor link.
I can see an id is available using kint(item) but cant seem to figure out the proper syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You can get The field collection item ID in field-collection-item.html.twig

```
{{ item['#field_collection_item'].id() }}
```

or you can get it from field-collection-item--field-name.html.twig, or other field template of field collection item.

```
{{ element['#items'].getEntity().id() }}
```

You can find these functions under Available Methods Tab when you printing out variables from twig template. You can use public methods.